# Writing PDF reader Library

Tags: c++, pdf, wxwidgets, lgpl

I have searched for PDF reader library that is licenced under LGPL or the like but could not find. I found only GPLs. Now I need a help to write my own library to read the PDF file and display it in my app. I have downloaded PDF Specs 1.7 from Adobe and I'm trying to search out a beginner tutorial but I'm yet to find one.
Is there a beginner tutorial for writing my own reader library (only reader)?
Thanks

Comment: Try [mupdf](http://code.google.com/p/sumatrapdf/source/browse/trunk/mupdf/README).

Comment: mupd is GPL, not LGPL like the OP was looking for.

Comment: anthony is right, I need more liberal like LGPL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't find a PDF read tutorial, why not try learning from a writer. If you want to integrate with wxWidgets, you may want to analyze the source of wxPdfDocument at http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/components/wxpdfdoc/

Comment: I have to try it that way. I don't think there is tutorial out there. I have not given up though